# How to evaluate integrals with infinite limits

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate the integral: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{4x^2+4x+5}$$ However, the upper limit of infinity is causing me some confusion (I have never encountered infinity in a definite integral before).

I want to use the substitution $x+\frac{1}{2} = \tan\theta$, so that the integral (ignoring limits) becomes:
$$\int\frac{dx}{4(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+4} = \int\frac{\sec^2\theta}{4(\tan^2\theta+1)} d\theta = \int\frac{1}{4} d\theta = \frac{\theta}{4} + c$$

However, I am unsure how to change limits. I can manage the lower one: $x = 0 \implies \theta = \arctan(\frac{1}{2})$. But for infinity, I don't know what to do. It seems to me that $\tan\theta = \infty$ has an infinite number of solutions ($\theta = \pm\frac{\pi}{2}, \pm\frac{3\pi}{2}, \pm\frac{5\pi}{2},...$), what does the upper limit become?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a short look at the theorem for [Substitution for single variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable)

I think your problem stems from the idea that your transformation function $\phi = \tan: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

However $\phi$ should be defined on some interval $I$ where it is differentiable. $\tan$ is not differentiable on whole $\mathbb{R}$ - it is if you choose just one section e.g. $(-0.5\pi, 0.5\pi)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. If one performs the change of variable
$$
\theta=\arctan \left(x+\frac12\right)
$$ then
$$
\theta(0)=\arctan \left(\frac12\right), \qquad \theta(\infty)=\arctan \left(\infty\right)=\frac{\pi}2,
$$ and, *as wanted*,
$$
x+\frac{1}{2} = \tan\theta,\qquad dx=\sec^2 \theta\:d\theta.
$$

**Remark**. We have made the change of variable
$$
\theta=\arctan \left(x+\frac12\right)
$$ *rather than*
$$
x+\frac{1}{2} = \tan\theta.
$$

Comment: The OP's question is not the change of variable. That was done correctly, the problem was to justify the choice of the upper limit. This does not answer that question.

Comment: @Gregory Please I invite you to read *correctly* my answer.

Comment: My understanding of arctan(x) is that it chooses the value closest to zero - as π/2 and -π/2 are equidistant from 0, why do we choose the positive value? It seems to me that choosing -π/2 is equally valid, but would yield a different result.

Comment: @Adam That's not the *standard* understanding. We have $$ y={\arctan}\ x\iff\tan x=y\text{ et }y\in\left]-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right[,$$see for example the table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Generalizations

Comment: Can the downvoter explain his downvote?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Ah, okay then. In that case, I must just be remembering a technically inexact mnemonic or simplification that I was taught in school.

Comment: @Adam I'm glad you have understood my above answer. Please feel free to upvote it ;) (don't understand *why* someone has downvoted it...).

Answer (score 0):

By definition:
$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{4x^2+4x+5}=\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_0^t\frac{dx}{4x^2+4x+5}$ , if this limit exists.